# Mesa Semantics without Starvation?

Tags: operating-systems, concurrency, synchronization

When a process inside a monitor with Mesa semantics finishes, another process can acquire the monitor. Now there can be starvation here when there is a thread with a lower priority.

Are there monitors of Mesa-semantics type that don't cause starvation and thus have bounded waiting?

Comment: I don't think that priority and bounded waiting mix particularly well in _any_ circumstance (monitors, mutual exclusion, even in lock-free synchronization).  I can't think of any circumstance under which allowing low-priority processes to proceed while there are higher-priority processes waiting wouldn't be a _priority inversion_.  I can't figure out how to make the term _starvation_ be meaningful in any circumstance other than threads of equal priority.

Comment: @WanderingLogic Well, it now sounds logical for threads with lower priorities to not have bounded waiting, now that you mentioned it. I guessed it right, you've been a professor. :-)